# How to rewind the pg_fetch_assoc($result, null) iterator

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm using pg_fetch_assoc to iterate over the result of an SQL query, but I need to do it several times and I can't find a way to "rewind" the iterator.

```
while ($record = pg_fetch_assoc($result, null)) {
    if ($record["position"] == $position_cell) {
        echo "<strong>J" . $record["order"] . " </strong>";
    };
}
```

So, if this $result contains 4 rows, I'll iterate over the four of them, but when I execute this code again, it will do nothing.

I know I can iterate with an integer instead of the null value, but then I'll have to calculate the number of rows, and I find this syntax quite convenient, so it will be great if you could tell me a way to do it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use

```
pg_result_seek($result, 0);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-seek.php

Comment: I don't know how I didn't find it. Thanks!